# retrieve the partition information in linux using c

Tags: c, linux-kernel

i need the program to tell me information like

> > number of partition. >> type of partition. >> file system type for that partion. >> start and end size of evry partition. the kind of output which the PRINT option for PARTED utility of linux displays
> >
> > number of partition. >> type of partition. >> file system type for that partion. >> start and end size of evry partition. the kind of output which the PRINT option for PARTED utility of linux displays

as an example the output should be like dis

Number Start End Size Type File system Flags
1 32.3kB 10.7GB 10.7GB primary reiserfs , , , , , , , , , type=83, ,
2 10.7GB 80.0GB 69.3GB extended boot, , , , , , lba, , , type=0f, , 5 10.7GB 57.6GB 46.9GB logical ext3 , , , , , , , , , type=83, ,
6 57.6GB 58.8GB 1234MB logical linux-swap , , , , , , , , , type=82, ,
7 58.8GB 80.0GB 21.2GB logical reiserfs , , , , , , , , , type=83, ,

but through a c code.

i know the file /proc/partions and /sys/block/sda from where i can get the data but i wonder how would the print option of parted utility retrieves dis data

Comment: What's wrong with `/proc/partitions`?

Comment: This is the third time you post this question! Stop deleting your question and reposting it verbatim.

Answer (score 1):

You can use fdisk source code for this needs:
[fdisk.c](ftp://ftp.nluug.nl/pub/os/Linux/distr/slackware/slackware-3.3/source/rescue/fdisk.c)
[fdisk.h](http://fossies.org/linux/misc/util-linux-ng-2.18.tar.gz%3aa/util-linux-ng-2.18/fdisk/fdisk.h)

Comment: @emil -i want to retrieve the start and end part of every partition ,exactly in the format at the print option of parted displays ...../proc/partition just provides the info of number of blocks occupied.

Comment: @joachim...........take a chill pill...i am new to this site and was facing some problem so it happened that way.And please focus on answering the question more please...;)